# Сменить контактные данные в шапке сайта

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Мне необходимо сменить и добавить новый номер телефона, но я не могу найти, где это можно сделать. Скрин прилагаю. Это эта часть, которая отображает контактные данные в шапке, не является виджетом, т.к. в админке, в разделе виджетов данный блок с контактными данными отсутствует.

Где я могу отредактировать номер телефона в этой шапке?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: как тема называется?

Comment: @ValeriiVasiliev, кажется вот эта - https://ibb.co/1fZWbKv. Обвёл красным квадратом.

Comment: да, это она - https://ibb.co/Ns1yBNX. Но в виджетах, как я уже писал в вопросе, этой шапки с телефонами нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Визуально похоже на admin_bar, но это не он.

Данные идут из настроек темы. Фрагмент верхушки шаблона

```
<div id="Action_bar" class="creative">
            <?php
                $action_bar = mfn_opts_get('action-bar');
                if( isset($action_bar['creative']) ){
                    get_template_part('includes/include', 'slogan');
                }

                if (has_nav_menu('social-menu')) {
                    mfn_wp_social_menu();
                } else {
                    get_template_part('includes/include', 'social');
                }
            ?>
        </div>
```

Нужно в теме найти файлы

```
includes/include-slogan.php
includes/include-social.php
```

В них посмотреть какие настройки подгружаются

Comment: нашел в файле `include-slogan.php` - https://ibb.co/tbq7s3M. Но опять же, в файле эти номера с почтой "жестко" не прописаны.

Comment: данные, как я понимаю тянутся с админки же?!   - - - -  `esc_attr(str_replace(' ', '', $header_phone)) .'">'. esc_html($header_phone)`

Comment: вы мне не подскажете, что дальше делать?

Comment: найдите в админке настройки темы. данные в настройках темы

Comment: найдите функцию mfn_opts_get() и посмотрите откуда она читает данные

Answer (score 1):

Тут в коде копать не нужно, в настройках темы посмотри. На BeTheme например так[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: уже не актуально, но все равно спасибо